# How to display uploaded image in asp .net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, url, file-upload

I uploaded an image to server using form fileData:

```
[Route("upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) {
                Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            var provider = GetMultipartProvider();

            var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            //Get Album name from Form
            var titleOfAlbum = GetTitleOfAlbum(provider);
            //get path to file
            var pathToCoverDecoded = result.FileData.First().LocalFileName;
            //Encodeing to base 64 path
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pathToCoverDecoded);
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            Album al = new Album();
            al.Title = titleOfAlbum;
            al.PathToCover = base64;
            db.Albums.Add(al);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);


        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }

    private string GetDesereleazedFileName(MultipartFileData fileData)
    {
        var fileName = GetFileName(fileData);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileName).ToString();
    }

   private string GetFileName(MultipartFileData fileData)
    {
        return fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
    }

    private MultipartFormDataStreamProvider GetMultipartProvider()
    {
        var uploadFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files");
        if (Directory.Exists(uploadFolder) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);
        }

        return new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadFolder);
    }

    private string GetTitleOfAlbum(MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider)
    {
        var titleOfAlbum = "";
        foreach(var key in provider.FormData.GetValues(0))
        {
            titleOfAlbum = key;
        }

        return titleOfAlbum;
    }


}
```

Path looks like:

> "C:\Users\Oops\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\ForMyCustomers\WebApplication1\Files\BodyPart_b40d80c5-47dc-41db-8e35-9d39d4e27939"

I getting path from FileData:
[image]

and convert it to base64, but it doesn't displays at page 
I've got File not found error.
How can I resolve it? if the URL is wrong how can I get correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use physical path (the one you used) on web. The physical path like **"C:\something"** is the path that can be used only by your OS.

The URL however, is the path that you need and to use and to do that you need to put your files somewhere that is readable by your host (IIS).

You are already writing your files in "~/Files". so you just need to add the file name at the end.

```
var url= "~/Files/"+filename;
```

you need to save the file name when you are uploading your file so when you want to fetch data from DB, fetch the file name from DB and create the url using that.